# 4wd rear differential compatibility

Tags: dodge, ram, 4wd, rear-differential, part-interchange

I have a **2001 Dodge Ram 1500 4wd** and in search of a rear differential a Chrysler 9.25 with 3.92 gear ratio. I'm wondering what other vehicles had this exact rear differential?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not too sure about this information, but from what I've seen, only 2000-2001 Ram 4x4 will have that same differential.